# Is there any shorter alternative to dispatch_once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Is there any shorter version? It feels like a lot of boilerplate.

I'm throwing in a couple of examples where I think it is tedious

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static id instance;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [self new];
    });
    return instance;
}

+ (NSString *)RFC2822StringFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
        formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
    });

    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Comment: Just saying: What are you going to do when Apple releases a slightly bigger iPhone?

Comment: @gnasher729 you just had to comment on that.

Comment: There's a built-in code completion short-cut in Xcode.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Well, why read 5 lines when you can read one?

Comment: @hfossli The "problem" with macros is, that other developers need to read the definition anyway, so in fact they read a lot more  ;) On the other hand, the dispatch_once is a well known idiom, which reads just as one "word" not a few lines. :)

Comment: Well, I must advocate for spending less time describing how stuff should happen and more time on what should happen. Isn't that in the same spirit as RXPromise? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a small macro which basically lets you write quite short stuff

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    return dispatch_once_and_return(id, [self new]);
}
```

Also blocks is supported with this semantic

```
+ (NSString *)altRFC2822StringFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = dispatch_once_and_return(NSDateFormatter *, ^{
        NSDateFormatter *f = [NSDateFormatter new];
        // setup formatter
        return f;
    }());

    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

(The trick is to add `()` after the block, which basically executes the block right away).

The macro

```
#define dispatch_once_and_return(type, value) ({\
    static type cachedValue;\
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;\
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{\
        cachedValue = value;\
    });\
    cachedValue;\
})
```

Comment: That's nice, but macros often obfuscate which makes it harder to maintain a program rather than easier.  I only use macros for repetitive tasks like filling in `static struct` entries, or calling the same methods with different values.  I'd rather type in the original string than use this macro.

Comment: Well, if GCD was to be extended with this macro you would see it differently, or not? (it wouldn't be extended, just a hypothetical question :)

Comment: No I would be confused.  When I type-out the longhand form I understand what `dispatch_once()` is doing.  I can see that there is a `static` instance of my singleton and I can see that there is the `static` "once token", which I prefer as in 6 months time I don't then have to find the macro definition and "work backwards" to determine what it's doing.  Therefore the macro is counter-productive to me.